# Why does the TFS2013 MultiBuildTemplate throw all binaries to test into the same folder?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, tfsbuild

We have a Microsoft TeamFoundationServer 2013.
Now we have many different TeamProjects with solutions.

Now I have to create a build-definition which builds many of those solutions at once. 
I can specify the build-output in the definition as follows: `Solution Specific Build Outputs: True`
So this puts the build-outputs of every single project to a folder with the according name.

But now, I have to run the unit-tests for every solution. If I just enable it, many of the tests fail.
This is because my BuildDefinition throws all binaries which it wants to test into the folder `TestResults\Deploy_USERNAME 2015-03-26 11_30_00\Out`. 
But now, there's the problem: Many of those projects contain a `app.config` for connection-strings (or a `web.config`). But obviously there can only be one such file in a single directory, so it overrides every file until the last project copies its `app.config` on top of all others. Now the unit-tests for that last project just run well, because it's got all necessary connection-string. But for all other projects, many will fail.

Is there an option to split those test-bins into different folders, just as the build-output?
Or is there any other workaround for this problem?

**Environment:**

Team Foundation Server 2013

Windows Server 2012

Build-Template: MultiBuildTemplate.xaml